# Google maps autocomplete not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I want to get the auto complete behaviour of the Google maps, but I am not getting the exact reason why it is showing this

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined **

where as I used this

```
  var addressValue = document.getElementById('geoFenceAddress');
  alert(addressValue);
  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(addressValue);
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', geoFenceAddress);
```

I have an element with id '**geoFenceAddress**' and infact the alert is showing this **[Object HTMLInputElement]**.

I am not understanding where I am lacking , please shed some light.........

:(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the places library when you load the API.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

Comment: You also need API key since the older way is no longer supported.